# css padding doesn't working in media

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have this css:

```
ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor {
    float: left;
    padding: .5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and this is the css on media

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 500px) {
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor
{
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
}
```

the padding in the media doesn't work, i mean the div still takes that previous padding , However, the background is changing to red. so why the padding still the old value?

#### Edit

This is how it looks in the normal size

[image]

This is what it looks when the window changes

[image]

This is how it looks when I remove the padding using the firebog

[image]

#### html

```
<img src="Styles/purpleLogo.gif" style="float:left;"/>
    <div id="newUpContainer" style="width: 100%; float: left;">
        <div id="onlineBookingDiv" style="float: right; width: 49%;  padding-bottom: 10px;">
            <div id="tabs">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Today</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tomorrow</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Any Date</a></li>
                    <li style="float: right; position: relative; right:2px">
                    <label >
                        <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="mealTimeSelector" OnSelectedIndexChanged="TodayTab_Click">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Breakfast</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">Lunch</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Dinner</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </label>
                        </li>
                </ul>
```

#### Edit2

Html from firefox page source

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true"><a href="#tabs-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Today</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false"><a href="#tabs-2" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Tomorrow</a></li>
                    <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="tabs-3" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="false"><a href="#tabs-3" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Any Date</a></li>
                    <li style="float: right; position: relative; right:2px">
                    <label>
                        <select name="ctl00$MainContent$mealTimeSelector" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$mealTimeSelector\',\'\')', 0)" id="MainContent_mealTimeSelector">
    <option selected="selected" value="1">Breakfast</option>
    <option value="2">Lunch</option>
    <option value="3">Dinner</option>

</select>
                    </label>
                        </li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Can you show us an example where this is happening?

Comment: @Zhihao Yes I will post image

Comment: We will probably also need the HTML as well to understanding what is going on and *why* it's happening. An image will only show us *what* is happening.

Comment: Please add your html,

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](http://jsbin.com/nebuziwo/1/edit?html,output). Whatever it is, it isn't caused by any of the code you've shared.

Comment: @Zhihao I added my html

Comment: @user3432257 — That's ASP.NET, not HTML.

Comment: @user3432257 — It also doesn't have any of the class names mentioned in your CSS.

Comment: @Quentin if the code that I shown is not relevant, why the background red works?

Comment: 1st, where is the `ui` class? I see it your css but not in html... is it a typo of `ul`

Comment: @Quentin yes asp.net, although I hate it but I have to work with it. What should I show you?

Comment: @user3432257 — http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: @Quentin I added the html again

Comment: The reason we ask for your HTML and not your ASP.NET markup is because the CSS is being applied to the HTML. If we have both the HTML and CSS, we can try recreating your situation ourselves for debugging. Giving us your ASP.NET markup does not help as much because it is rendered differently when the page is sent to the client.

Comment: @SULTAN I added the html again, check it please

Comment: @Zhihao I gave you the html from firefox source

Comment: This works in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2B7d/) I've set up. I suspect something else is overriding the padding, which you should be able to see using your browser developer tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 500px) {
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav .ui-tabs-anchor
    {
        float: left;
        background-color:red;
        padding: 0 !important;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

I have not seen evidence that padding is not being set elsewhere.
This method will force overwrite of padding.

Alternatively try setting padding in media to a positive padding and remove default padding to see if it takes effect. This will ensure the media query is working.

Comment: While this may give the desired result, I would consider this more of a hack that doesn't actually "solve" the problem. This may also introduce more problems down the road.

Comment: @user3432257 Please see my comment to the question. Adding `!important` basically makes it override everything else, but if the same problem comes up again then you won't be able to use `!important`. Simply using `!important` because you don't know where the problem is coming from will usually just cause more problems later on.

Comment: I should note I added the above solution to help diagnose the problem. I don't recommend it as a solution. If using important works then it indicates that the padding is being set elsewhere either in javascript or another css file.